# Converting conditional subtour elimination of CVRP into normal ones

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linearization

I am trying to **eliminate** the **if condition constraints** from the following CVRP formulation.

[image]

I tried some big M methods on paper but failed to come up with a proper reformulation. Can you please help me to find a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the equation into two inequalities and the apply the big-M method:

```
ui + qj <= uj + M(1-xij)
ui + qj >= uj - M(1-xij)
```

Models with big-M constants tend to be weak and numerically instable, so I suggest to select the constant as small as possible (i.e. make M depend on ij, if possible). To learn more about that have a look at the [Perils of "Big M"](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/07/perils-of-big-m.html).

Comment: Great! I don't know why I did not try this combination of the formulation. Thanks a lot!